# How to retrieve data from the external website using curl?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to retrieve data from the external website.

This is the main website

```
https://www.website.com/index.php?page=members
```

Inside above website there is a gallery page

```
https://www.website.com/index.php?page=listUsers&memId=52
```

When I check the network,I found that following script are used to gather the required data.

```
url: 'model/listUsersDb/listUsersAjax.php',
  type: 'POST',
  async: false,
  responseType: "json",
```

What I have tried so far is use curl method, But I dont know how to pass the parameters. Can anybody please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php Curl adding Params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367761/php-curl-adding-params)

Comment: If the remote site uses ajax to populate some of the content, then you're not going to be able to use cURL.  You'll need to use a library such as [PhantomJS](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs).