# How i can send get parameters in PHP Curl?

Tags: php, curl

i tryed to use:

```
    $qry_str = "ft_dl={$ow_ft_dl}&ft_dl_name={$singername} - $songen ({$ow_quality[$i]}).mp3&ft_dl_cover={$src}&sn_name={$singername}&songname={$songen}";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, OW_DL_HOST_FUNC . '?' . $qry_str);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_exec($ch);
```

but when i start the code, i dont have any actions to the target file...

> the OW_DL_HOST_FUNC file value like : http://sitename.deve/file.php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367761/php-curl-adding-params

Comment: Try using CURLOPT_HTTPGET though I am not sure if it serves your purpose.